# Mimekit send email Apple does not render html

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mimekit

When I send emails through `C#` using library **Mimekit** everything is fine, but when I want to open them from the Apple application, the screen is blank (it does not interpret the `html` or `CSS`)

```
var email = new MimeMessage();
            email.Sender = MailboxAddress.Parse(_mailSettings.Value.Mail);
            email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(mail.Email));
            email.Subject = mail.Subject;

            var builder = new BodyBuilder();
            builder.HtmlBody = mail.Body;
            email.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();

            using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Connect(_mailSettings.Value.Host, _mailSettings.Value.Port, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
            smtp.Authenticate(_mailSettings.Value.Mail, _mailSettings.Value.Password);

            await smtp.SendAsync(email);
            smtp.Disconnect(true);
```

[Here Image Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQl8W.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `email.Sender = MailboxAddress.Parse(_mailSettings.Value.Mail);`, you should be using `email.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(_mailSettings.Value.Mail));`

The `Sender` header works like the `From` header, but is only meant to be used if it is different from the `From` header or if the `From` header contains multiple addresses.

That may or may not fix the Apple mail rendering issue (the mail rendering issue is probably an HTML code issue, not an email issue).

Comment: yes, the error is in the html code (I was able to solve it)